# How can I figure out what audio file is playing?

Tags: windows, audio, api

Say I play an audio file from any application. Is there a way to track down where it's coming from? Like a way to interface with the Windows Audio Service?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly not all applications have a source for the audio file...

Comment: Are you know which specific file or you don't? If you know then just use Sysinternals Handle / Process Explorer and look for that file.

Comment: I know the applications that could be accessing an audio file. Basically I'd like to know which file it accessed. I assumed I could interface with Windows Audio since it's playing the file. Perhaps this is more a SO question, as I'm looking to do this via VB.NET.

Comment: @user287848 Assuming that your application keeps file handles opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733384/how-to-enumerate-process-handles